# How to import the app using flask foundation?

Tags: python, flask

I am using [Flask foundation](https://github.com/JackStouffer/Flask-Foundation) to begin with my new flask app.

The **init**.py file has a method:

```
def create_app(object_name, env="prod"):
    """
    An flask application factory, as explained here:
    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/

    Arguments:
        object_name: the python path of the config object,
                     e.g. sservice.settings.ProdConfig

        env: The name of the current environment, e.g. prod or dev
    """

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(object_name)
    app.config['ENV'] = env

    #init the cache
    cache.init_app(app)

    debug_toolbar.init_app(app)

    #init SQLAlchemy
    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # Import and register the different asset bundles
    assets_env.init_app(app)
    assets_loader = PythonAssetsLoader(assets)
    for name, bundle in assets_loader.load_bundles().iteritems():
        assets_env.register(name, bundle)

    # register our blueprints
    from controllers.main import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

that is imported in manage.py.

But what If I need to use this app variable to access the application configuration in modules within the application? I can't use current_app outside request contexts. Creating one is ugly.

I need to have a app variable in my *models.py* file:

In models.py

```
# how to import? Below doesn't work
from appname import app

# access config
print(app.config)
```

I can't call this method create_app, because it should be only called once to create the application. Not anytime you need to import the app. How should I solve this?

I only want to use create_app() exactly once outside the package to give it the wsgi server, but I don't want to use it within the package.

Comment: A little more detail on *why* you need to access the app's config outside of a request context may help - as it stands, this sounds like an [X / Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/134376)

Comment: I want to save some constant data in the app's configuration, like the base path or some other constants. The should remain in the settings.py file and shouldn't be spread all over the package. Therefore I need the app variable. When I import the settings directly, the whole cascading stuff that flask's configuration does is ignored.

Comment: So you have module or package-level variables in your program that depend on the app's configuration, but cannot be put in the app's config?

Comment: I have logic that depends on configuration that resides in settings.py. I want to import the current configuration (Prod, Debug, Test, ...) for my app, because I want to centralize the configuration for my application and want to use existing configuration flask implementation. But I can't access the app.config attribute. When I am thinking wrong, a little hint would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

What is working now for me:

Wherever there is no current_app (outside of request contexts I guess) just use something like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('appname.settings_file.DevConfig')
print(app.config)
```